# google map not loading properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

hi every one i am trying to implement google map with marker in my project for that i am using the following code.

in my html

```
<div id="googleMap" style="height: 243px;"></div>
```

then in script

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        var map;
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.896452, 77.595717),
                zoom: 17,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            function createMarker(options, html) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);
                if (html) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                        infoWindow.setContent(html);
                        infoWindow.open(options.map, this);
                    });
                }
                return marker;
            }
            var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(12.896452, 77.595717),
                map: map,
                label: {
                    text: "Kanti Industries",
                    color: "#9f1b1f",
                    fontSize: "15px",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                },
                title: 'Kanti Industries',
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=****" ></script>
```

Now the odd problem is that when i uploaded the files on the server, on my laptop the map gets loaded and everything works fine but when i open the same page on other device like from browser of my mobile or some other laptop it does not loads and i get "oops" error...

now i don't have access to other PC to inspect or see what is the error in console. i checked everything the API key is right, i changed a few things to check if i am writing the correct URL, i accessed it from chrome, IE and Firefox. Every browser on my PC loads the map, i also cleared cache and all.

Here is another link of different server where i am using same code but here it is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding http restrictions in my api key. Actually the client was using http// and i was using https//.